# Angular add to favourites

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list of items, and on each item I have a button where I can click "Add to favourites" and then a variable should be set to true, and a class is enabled..

in my controller, I've set $scope.isFavourite = false - When clicking a button I set the $scope.isFavourite = true

The problem with this is that all items on the page gets the class

The code here:
HTML:

```
<button ng-click="addToFav()" ng-class="{'active' : isFavourite}"><i class="ion-heart"></i> Netto</button>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.addToFav = function () {
$ionicPopup.show({
  title: 'Tilføj til favoritter',
  subTitle: 'Ønsker du at tilføje denne butik til dine favoritter?',
  scope: $scope,
  buttons: [
    { text: 'Nej' },
    {
      text: '<b>Ja</b>',
      type: 'button-positive',
      onTap: function(e) {
        $scope.isFavourite = true;
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

};

The problem is that when clicking, it doesn't isolate it to the button you've clicked, but at a global level instead which means that every button in my list gets the class="active", where it only should be the button i've clicked

Comment: Are you repeating through an array of favorites?

Comment: Right now, it's just static content, however later on data is coming from a webservice

Comment: Something like this?  They also toggle.  https://jsfiddle.net/tud0jk1d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `scope: $scope` you are setting the scope to your surrounding controller scope, so all of your popups sharing the same `isFavourite` variable.

You could do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button ng-click="addToFav(item)" ng-class="{'active' : item.isFavourite}"><i class="ion-heart"></i> Netto</button>
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.addToFav = function (item) {
    $ionicPopup.show({
        title: 'Tilføj til favoritter',
        subTitle: 'Ønsker du at tilføje denne butik til dine favoritter?',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [
            { text: 'Nej' },
            { text: '<b>Ja</b>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    item.isFavourite = true;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Working plunker:

http://codepen.io/kbkb/pen/ONzgBQ?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to look into Angular Components (some documentation can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). Basically a component is a reusable piece of code that has it's own scope, so changes made to one component don't affect the others. I would go into more detail, but I don't know Angular as well as I do Angular 2.